# How to hide the header icons for all visuals on the report?

Tags: powerbi

Every visual has header icons that shows the filter setting, export option, etc.

The header icons can be hidden at the report visual level. I want to hide this for all visuals and currently the only way I know of doing this is on each visual.

How to hide the header icons for all visuals entire report without having to do it on each visual?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an out of the box feature to globally hide header icons for all visuals in an entire report with a click but you can use a workaround by more efficiently using the selection plan and applying the changes to multiple visuals at the same time

- from home, go to View in the ribbon, then enable the selection pane
- using ctrl select each visual you want to impact
- then go to visualizations pane, grab the paintbrush icon to open format
- expand the the visual header section
- set the off option for the icon property.
- this will hide the header icons for all the selected visuals

repeat as needed for other report pages.
Not a one click and done setting, but a bit better then clicking each one; hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do this in the Workspace > Report > Settings.
You can change the header settings there at once!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).